# How do I say "any of ~"

Tags: translation

Please tell me how to say

> Please click any (one of the) button on the menu.

I have tried to search translation or grammar about "any of" but most results came out to be どれも. It doesn't seems to fit in the sentence. I thought of saying

> メニューのボタンをクリックしてください。どれでもいいです。

But it seems long and I am looking for a way to say it in a sentence. Any advice?

Edit:
I really like use of the word 任意. I have not seen any one uses 「任意のボタン」tho. What do you think about「メニューの任意のボタンをクリックしてください」? Does that sounds right?

Edit:
How about どれか一つ or いずれかの

Comment: The most common translation I can see for 'press any key' is 任意の キーを押す.  For 'press any button' an acceptable translation is どれかの ボタンを 押します. So, for 'please press any button in the menu', you could probably say メニューのどれかのボタンを 押してください.

Comment: First, 任意 is a good translation for any, but it sounds a little too formal, so I prefer お好きな for it. Secondly, as for the sentence on the screen, I think, the shorter the better unless it is misread. So, I would like to omit the "menu", then the translation will be like どれかボタンをクリックしてください。/ どれかお好きなボタンをクリックしてください。

Comment: I found several translations of any key/button and some use 任意. However, mackygoo is a native speaker, unlike me, and he says above it comes across as too formal. As your proposed sentence looks similar to some of the example sentences I looked at and which were saying the same thing, it doesn't look wrong and I'm sure it's easily comprehensible. But if you're more particular about it, you could see if there is a better version.

Comment: Sorry in my first comment I meant dochiraka, not doreka. Izureka works too. I saw example sentences using it, but it was less common. My source was linguee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Edit:
>   How about どれか一つ or いずれかの

Yes, I think they would work. I think you could say...

> メニュー[内]{ない}のいずれかのボタンをクリックしてください。

or maybe...

> ｛メニュー内の or メニューにある｝ボタンを｛いずれか or どれか｝一つクリックしてください。

Answer (score 1):

Using どちらでも would work well.

> メニューからのボタンをどちらでもクリックしてください

Or, you could use a phrase they use often at ticket machines in train stations:

> ご希望{きぼう}のボタンを押してください
>
> Please press the desired button.

Then you could change the wording to fit your needs. Eg Using クリック instead of 押す.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I remembered another structure although I'm not quite sure it fits well, but what about using どちら? For example I would say something like this:

> メニューからどちらのボタンをクリックしてください。

I know it would mean "Please click whichever button from the menu." With the use of どちら or even どちらでも, it's usually used when you have to make a selection between two choices (between A and B). As per your example, it is not stated how many buttons there are on the menu, so anyone can click whichever right? Either that one or that one.

Comment: Add ka to dochira and it will look better - I.e. dochiraka. I checked several English-Japanese parallel sentences and they were consistent on this point. There are other ways of saying 'any', but dochiraka is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Many times you can't do direct translations of English and Japanese. With regard to UI design, why are you saying:

"*Please click any (one of the) button on the menu.*"

instead of

"*Please click a button on the menu.*"

(1) Why say "... *any **one of the** buttons*..."
Clicking more than 1 button is impossible.

(2) informing a user that an active button is not clickable violates UI convention. The non-clickable buttons must be dimmed-out (disabled). Presented a set of active buttons, the user already knows **any** of them are clickable.

You are missing the intuitive properties of a GUI interface. A user immediately understands that a collection of active buttons means "*any one of them is clickable*".

You really just need to say "*Please select a button on the menu.*". Or

"*メニューにあるボタンをクリックしてください。*"